# probability value of a very small set?

Tags: probability

Consider $R^n$ space and some continuous density $p_X(x)$. I want to evaluate the probability of a very small connected set $A$ that includes $x_0$.

Then, is it true that $\lim_{vol(A) \to 0} \frac{p_X(x_0)Leb(A)}{p_X(A)}=1$??

Basically I want to represent $p_X(A) = p_X(x_0)*volume(A)$ for very small $A$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not necessarily true. It is true if $x_0$ is a Lebesgue point of $p_X$.

Comment: Thanks Kavi. I found this statement: given any $f \in L^{1}$, almost every $x$ is a Lebesgue point of $f$.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_point
Because here $p_X$ is a valid continuous density function, does it hold?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the continuity assumption. Every point is a Lebsgue point by continuity. Hence the result is true for every $x_0$.

Comment: thank you! now it is clear!!